# Intel Celeron N2840 and Elementary OS 5.0 Juno

Tags: release-juno, intel

I have a laptop **Lenovo G50-30** **(Intel Celeron N2840, 4GB of RAM, NVIDIA 820M)**. Will this OS normally work on this device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes elementary OS [release-juno](/questions/tagged/release-juno) will run on your computer.